# fail to move data from one table to another in sql

Tags: php

The structure and data types are all the same, but can't move data between tables in the same database..
I have 2 tables tempo_sales and sales

```
mysql_query("insert into sales select * from tempo_sales");
```

The same program algorithm works with other database, but with the current database m working with, t seems impossible  to get  through

Comment: *insert into sales select * from*? `INSERT` and `SELECT`?

Comment: define "other database"

Comment: what type of database you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try your query like below

```
INSERT INTO sales ( 
  field1, 
  field2, 
  field3, 
  field4 ) 
SELECT field1, 
  field2, 
  field3, 
  field4 
FROM tempo_sales ORDER BY field1 ASC
```